# Spring task fixed-delay within specific timeframe

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I want to have spring configured task which will be running with `fixed-delay` but only within specific timeframe, lets say 6am - 6pm.

I understand I can have fixed delay like:

```
<task:scheduled ref="myBean" method="myMethod" fixed-delay="60000" />
```

or run every lets say hour within a timeframe with:

```
<task:scheduled ref="myBean" method="myMethod" cron="0 * 6-18 * * MON-FRI" />
```

How can I combine these? Sure I can do the check for the timeframe from within my bean but I was looking for some pure Spring way of doing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make your own custom [Trigger](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/Trigger.html).
Check out [this page](http://vladjuylov.com/custom-trigger-for-spring-scheduling#.UGrfhVG13U8) for more information on how to create your own trigger

Comment: Yes, that looks right, let me implement one and then accept the answer :) +1 sofar